# How to override hook_page_build?

Tags: 7, hooks

I have below code coming from [External Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/extlink) module in Drupal 7:

```
/**
* Implements hook_page_build().
*/
function extlink_page_build() {
   $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'extlink');
   drupal_add_js($path .'/extlink.js', array('every_page' => TRUE));
   drupal_add_js(array('extlink' => array(
     'extTarget'     => variable_get('extlink_target', 0),
     'extClass'      => variable_get('extlink_class', 'ext'),
     'extLabel'      => check_plain(variable_get('extlink_label', t('(link is external)'))),
     'extImgClass'   => variable_get('extlink_img_class', 0),
     'extSubdomains' => variable_get('extlink_subdomains', 1),
     'extExclude'    => variable_get('extlink_exclude', ''),
     'extInclude'    => variable_get('extlink_include', ''),
     'extCssExclude' => variable_get('extlink_css_exclude', ''),
     'extCssExplicit' => variable_get('extlink_css_explicit', ''),
     'extAlert'      => variable_get('extlink_alert', 0),
     'extAlertText'  => variable_get('extlink_alert_text', 'This link will take you to an external web site. We are not responsible for their content.'),
     'mailtoClass'   => variable_get('extlink_mailto_class', 'mailto'),
     'mailtoLabel'   =>   check_plain(variable_get('extlink_mailto_label', t('(link sends e-mail)'))),
   )), 'setting');
}
```

I want to add below code from above function only if my some condition is true (which will be based on some user filed) , without overriding files of module it self:

`drupal_add_js(array('extlink' => array(
    'extTarget'     => variable_get('extlink_target', 0),)), 'setting');`

I am not getting any solution how to override this function thorough my custom module, Please suggest !

To make more clear I just want to add condition in above function so that js will only get added if condition according to user field is true.

**UPDATE: I have tried like below code but its not working, please suggest what I am doing wrong** My custom module name: `custom_overrides`

```
function custom_overrides_page_alter(&$page) {
   global $user;
   $userid = $user->uid; 

    if($userid){
        $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'extlink');
        drupal_add_js($path .'/extlink.js', array('every_page' => TRUE));
        drupal_add_js(array('extlink' => array('extTarget' => variable_get('extlink_target', 0),)), 'setting');
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution to my question in this way:

```
function news_js_alter(&$javascript) {

   $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'extlink');
   global $user;
   $userid = $user->uid;
   if (!$userid) {
    unset($javascript[$path . '/extlink.js']);
   }
}
```

Module was adding js settings, so I wanted to add only when user was loged in, so now in my theme **news** I have added above code in **template.php** and it worked. May this help other users trying to solve similar conditions.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any other way how I can unset only required variable only  like "extTarget" in js settings with js_alter rather than unset complete file  ? If some one having look on this please suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

In [hook_page_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) you can override *js* settings just by using *drupal_add_js* like you pasted above.

Comment: Thanks for your help , but I already tried like this. I have update code in questions, please suggest what I am doing wrong ? Thanks!

Comment: I think its  hook_hook_page_alter or like you provided  hook_page_build_alter

Comment: you're using hook_page_alter, try hook_page_build_alter

Comment: Thx but It seems there is no hook like page_build_alter in your provided link as well, but I tried still no effect , any other ideas ?

Comment: sorry you're right .. should be hook_page_alter - is your code executed ? what's inside drupal_get_js ? why are you readding the extlink.js ?

Comment: Actually I just want to add above Js settings only when user have certain checkbox filed checked but for now I am trying with loged in user condition. If  I am not following write code , please suggest how to alter js settings

Comment: Thanks for you all help, but above is answer how I solved situation. I hope I am doing in right way. Any suggestion to do it in better way? Is that ok to use template.php of my theme in this way, any ideas ?

Comment: Is there any way how I can unset only required variable only  like "extTarget" in js settings with js_alter rather than unset complete file  ?